# Markov property vs. Martingale property

Tags: martingales, markov-process

Let $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ be a sequence of random variables with an arbitrary distribution $q$ and existing expectancy value.

How can I check, if the following sequences hold the markov property or the martingale property?

1) $(S_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$, where $S_n:=Y_1+...+Y_n$

2) $(T_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$, where $T_n:=Y_{n-1}+Y_n$

3) $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$, where $M_n:=max\{Y_1,...,Y_n\}$

Does a sequence exist, which hold the martingale property, but not the markov property?

I really hope someone can help with these questions.

Greetings

Comment: Well, you can always use the definitions.

Comment: I don't know how to use the definition to prove that. Can someone give an example?

Comment: $S_n$ is a martingale (wrt to its natural filtration) if $E(S_n|\mathscr{F}_n)=S_{n-1}$ by definition. Rewrite $S_n=Y_n+S_{n-1}$ and use the fact the latter summand is in $\mathscr{F}_n$ and we conclude that $S$ is a martingale only if $E(Y_n)=...$ (for you to finish)

Comment: Expanding from Nap D.Lover.  The first partial sum is almost immediately implied from the definition of a Martingale. Hope this helps.

Comment: $S$ is a martingale only if $E(Y_n) = S_n-S_{n-1}$?

Comment: @Tino no an unconditional expectation cannot be a random variable. $Y$ must have mean zero to finish my argument.

Comment: That means $S_n = S_{n-1}$?

Comment: How can I prove if the sequences hold the markov property?

Comment: @Tino no. I will write up in detail an answer for $1)$ for martingales since its not getting across. I suggest reviewing your notes and book for examples.

Comment: Actually, I am confused about the definition of markov and martingale. Can someone summarize in words, what the property of them are?

Comment: That should be in your book or notes. What is confusing?

Comment: If you are new to Martingales, it takes some amount of chewing with definition and examples. No need to panic! The natural filtration $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ of a process $X_{n}$  has the operational significance that it captures the available amount of information about the process at time $n$. Martingale is a process defined w.r.t a filtration process. A martingale can be thought of as a fair game. A game where the expectation of the process at time $n + 1$ given the information at time $n$ is equal to the value of the process at time $n$.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between the martingale property and the markov property. Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2):

For i.i.d $\left\{X_{i}\right\}_{i\ge 1 }$ with $\mathbb{E}\left[X_{i}\right]=0$

\begin{eqnarray*}
S_{n} &=& \sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_{i}}
\end{eqnarray*}
is a Martingale relative to filtration generated by the random variables  $X_{n}$ (i.e., the sequence w.r.t the sequence $0,X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$. Recall that, the definition of sequence $S_{n}$  to be a Martingale (w.r.t filtration $\mathcal{F}_{n\ge0}$ is that $\mathbb{E}\left[ S_{n+1} \lvert  \mathcal{F}_{n}\right] = S_{n}, \forall n>0$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{E}\left[ S_{n+1} \lvert  \mathcal{F}_{n}\right] &=&  \mathbb{E}\left[ S_{n}+X_{n+1}\lvert  \mathcal{F}_{n}\right] \\
&=&  \mathbb{E}\left[ S_{n} \lvert  \mathcal{F}_{n}\right]  + \mathbb{E}\left[  X_{n+1}\lvert  \mathcal{F}_{n}\right]  \\
&=&  S_{n}   + \mathbb{E}\left[  X_{n+1}\right]  \\
&=&  S_{n} 
\end{eqnarray*}

The 3rd one I guess is also relatively easy to establish the Markov property.

\begin{eqnarray*}
M_{n+1} &=&\max \left(Y_{1},Y_{2},\ldots,Y_{n+1}\right) \\
              &=& \max \left(\max\left(Y_{1},Y_{2},\ldots,Y_{n} \right),Y_{n+1}\right) \\
              &=& \max \left(M_{n},Y_{n+1}\right) \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Clearly, the state $M_{n+1}$ depends only the present state $M_{n}$ and the new input $Y_{n+1}$. In other words, given $M_{n}$, the state $M_{n+1}$ is conditionally independent of the past $Y_{i}\lvert_{i\le n} $.

Comment: $S_{n+1}$ as defined in your post is not equal to $S_n X_{n+1}$. I think you are missing a plus sign. Further you must assume the $X$ have mean zero for this to work, which could be made explicit here.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks Nap D. Lover.  Shall fix that.

Comment: Forgot to add that the 2nd one $T_{n}$ is not Markov. It is a sliding window sum which clearly is not Markov. The transition matrix simply varies. Hopefully you can workout the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed answer to 1) that I hope you can use to inform your attempts for the other problems (at least for the martingale part).

A sequence of RVs $S=(S_n)$ is a martingale with respect to a filtration $\mathscr{F}_n$ if 
$$\mathbb{E}(S_{n+1} | \mathscr{F}_n)=S_{n}$$ 
for all $n$. Also $S$ must be *adapted* to the filtration, i.e. $S_n \in \mathscr{F}_n$ for all $n$. Intuitively this is interpreted to mean that given all the information up to time $n$, then one knows the value of $S_n$.

We assume the question wants to use the natural filtrations $\mathscr{F}_n=\sigma(Y_1,\dotsc, Y_n)$.

If $S_n=Y_1+\dotso +Y_n$ and with $Y=(Y_n)$ a sequence of independent RVs with common mean, then we first note that we can write
$$S_{n+1}=Y_{n+1}+S_{n},$$
then taking the conditional expectation gives
$$\mathbb{E}(S_{n+1} | \mathscr{F}_n)=\mathbb{E}(Y_{n+1}+S_{n}| \mathscr{F}_n)$$
$$=\mathbb{E}(Y_{n+1}| \mathscr{F}_n)+\mathbb{E}(S_{n} | \mathscr{F}_n),$$
using linearity. Now since each $Y$ is independent, we know that $Y_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_n$. Thus $\mathbb{E}(Y_{n+1}|\mathscr{F}_n)=\mathbb{E}(Y_{n+1})$. Second, $S_{n}$ is $\mathscr{F}_n$-measurable, hence $\mathbb{E}(S_n | \mathscr{F}_n)=S_n$. Therefore, the last displayed equation becomes now,
$$\mathbb{E}(S_{n+1} | \mathscr{F}_n)=\mathbb{E}(Y_{n+1})+S_n$$
but we want the RHS to **just contain** $S_n$ to match the above definition. This only occurs when $\mathbb{E}(Y_n)=0$ for all $n$. Therefore we have proven *any sequence of mean-zero independent RVs forms a martingale w.r.t. the natural filtration*. Further, this imposes *no changes* on $Y_n$ other than the mean being zero and hence no changes on $S_n$ other than $\mathbb{E}(S_n)=\mathbb{E}(Y_1)+\dotsc+\mathbb{E}(Y_n)=0$.

Check out *Probability with Martingales* by D. Williams and *Markov Chains* by J.R. Norris for extremely well-written presentations of these topics.